# catkin_make error | ROS Melodic and OpenCV 3.4.0

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After clonning the repository, given in the leg_detector ros.org page, to my catkin workspace and after performing the cakin_make I get the following error:

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/joao-nisa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/face_detector/face_detector
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/joao-nisa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/leg_detector/leg_detector
CMakeFiles/leg_detector.dir/src/leg_detector.cpp.o: In function `LegDetector::laserCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
leg_detector.cpp:(.text._ZN11LegDetector13laserCallbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN11LegDetector13laserCallbackERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs10LaserScan_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x4ca): undefined reference to `cv::ml::RTrees::getVotes(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
people/leg_detector/CMakeFiles/leg_detector.dir/build.make:215: recipe for target '/home/joao-nisa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/leg_detector/leg_detector' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/joao-nisa/catkin_ws/devel/lib/leg_detector/leg_detector] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4646: recipe for target 'people/leg_detector/CMakeFiles/leg_detector.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [people/leg_detector/CMakeFiles/leg_detector.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[100%] Built target face_detector
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I've installed the Melodic version of ROS and the version of OpenCV is the 3.4.0.
Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329353/catkin_make-error-%7C-ros-melodic-and-opencv-3.4.0/) by [nisa20](https://answers.ros.org/users/44304/nisa20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like it will either work or not work depending on whether you have [this PR](https://github.com/wg-perception/people/pull/68). Try rolling it back (or checking out the `kinetic` branch).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nisa20](https://answers.ros.org/users/44304/nisa20/) on 2019-08-01**:
Thanks, that worked!

However, when I launch the leg_detector I get the following error:

```
[ WARN] [1564669364.430665292]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

I changed the bagfile to the following:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector" args="scan:=base_scan $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen">
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="odom"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Because, before I change my bagfile to what is presented above, I got the same error but target instead of odom was odom_combined.

But as you can see, that doesn't seem to work.

How can I get the detection results?

Thanks in advance @David Lu

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2020-04-23**:
Rolling back to **9fcbc87** commit helped, not to **origin/kinetic** branch.